# Gameboy emulator in C

Tags: c, windows, sdl, virtual-machine

I've been coding a Gameboy emulator in C for some time(seems like a common project for people).  It's reasonably functional and has some MBC1 support, but has some minor graphical glitches still.  I've coded on and off for a long time, but consider myself still very much an amateur and have no professional experience.

The code is very much a work in progress.  I realize the error-handling is lax. 
 I'm just looking for some general critiques.  I would like to try and start a career in software development, but don't have the benefit of a degree.  Would something like this be reasonable for a portfolio and to put on a resume?  If not, are there parts of the code that stick out and say "unprofessional"?

This is the emulation code of the project. The rest of the code, including I/O and screen drawing support, is [on GitHub](https://github.com/bcrew1375/Miracle-GB/tree/2da4ed168b420511a62f2fc66216bbdeb57f3ec7).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <sdl.h>
#include <windows.h>

#include "define.h"

struct Emulation
{
    struct MemoryMap
    {
        unsigned char romBank0[0x4000];     // Primary rom bank from 0x0000-0x3FFF.
        unsigned char romBank1[0x4000];     // Secondary rom bank from 0x4000-0x7FFF (Switchable on MBC carts).
        unsigned char videoRam[0x2000];     // The Gameboy's 8 KB video RAM from 0x8000-0x9FFF.
        unsigned char ramBank[0x2000];      // An 8 KB switchable RAM bank that is supported by some cartridges from 0xA000-0xBFFF.
        unsigned char internRam[0x2000];    // The Gameboy's 8 KB internal RAM from 0xC000-0xDFFF, this is also echoed from 0xE000-FDFF.
        unsigned char sprite[0xA0];         // Sprite Attribute Memory (OAM) from 0xFE00-0xFE9F.
                                            // The address space from FEA0-FEFF is unusable.
        unsigned char ioRegs[0x4C];         // I/O registers from 0xFF00-0xFF4B.  FF03, FF08-FF0E, FF15, FF1F, and FF27-FF2F are unused.
                                            // The address space from FF4C-FF7F is unusable.
        unsigned char highRam[0x7F];        // The Gameboy's high RAM from 0xFF80-FFFE.
        unsigned char intrpFlags;           // The interrupt enable(IE) flags at 0xFFFF.
    } memory;

    struct Cartridge
    {
        int systemType;
        int mbcType;
        unsigned char romBankRegister;  // This will store the currently selected MBC ROM bank.
        unsigned char dataBuffer[16777216];  // Set a maximum cartridge size at 16 megabytes.
    } cart;

    struct CPU
    {
        union Registers
        {
            struct { unsigned short int AF, BC, DE, HL, SP, PC; };
            struct { unsigned char F, A, C, B, E, D, L, H, SPL, SPH, PCL, PCH; };
        } regs;
    } cpu;

    struct State
    {
        boolean eiDelay;  // EI instruction enables interrupts one instruction after its execution.
        boolean intrpEnable;  // Master interrupt enable switch.
        boolean halted;
        boolean haltInstructionRepeat;
        boolean running;
        boolean stopped;
    } state;

    struct Cycles
    {
        unsigned short int internalCounterCycles;  // Cycle counter for DIV and TIMA register.
        unsigned short int previousInternalCounterCycles;  // Cycle counter for DIV and TIMA register.
        unsigned short int timaIncCounterCycles;  // A cycle counter for incrementing the TIMA register.
        unsigned int frameCycles;
        unsigned int statCycles;  // Cycle counter for STAT register.
        unsigned char opCycles[0x100];  // Store the number of clock cycles for every instruction
        unsigned char opCBCycles[0x100];  // Store cycles for CB bit instructions
    } cycles;

    struct IO
    {
        struct Display
        {
            unsigned char bgBuffer[256][256];
        };
    } io;
} emu;

// Standard Gameboy opcode clock cycles.
unsigned char GB_CycleTable[0x100] = { //0x00 0x01 0x02 0x03 0x04 0x05 0x06 0x07 0x08 0x09 0x0A 0x0B 0x0C 0x0D 0x0E 0x0F
                                 /*0x00*/  4,  12,   8,   8,   4,   4,   8,   4,  20,   8,   8,   8,   4,   4,   8,   4,
                                 /*0x10*/  0,  12,   8,   8,   4,   4,   8,   4,  12,   8,   8,   8,   4,   4,   8,   4,
                                 /*0x20*/  8,  12,   8,   8,   4,   4,   8,   4,   8,   8,   8,   8,   4,   4,   8,   4,
                                 /*0x30*/  8,  12,   8,   8,  12,  12,  12,   4,   8,   8,   8,   8,   4,   4,   8,   4,
                                 /*0x40*/  4,   4,   4,   4,   4,   4,   8,   4,   4,   4,   4,   4,   4,   4,   8,   4,
                                 /*0x50*/  4,   4,   4,   4,   4,   4,   8,   4,   4,   4,   4,   4,   4,   4,   8,   4,
                                 /*0x60*/  4,   4,   4,   4,   4,   4,   8,   4,   4,   4,   4,   4,   4,   4,   8,   4,
                                 /*0x70*/  8,   8,   8,   8,   8,   8,   0,   8,   4,   4,   4,   4,   4,   4,   8,   4,
                                 /*0x80*/  4,   4,   4,   4,   4,   4,   8,   4,   4,   4,   4,   4,   4,   4,   8,   4,
                                 /*0x90*/  4,   4,   4,   4,   4,   4,   8,   4,   4,   4,   4,   4,   4,   4,   8,   4,
                                 /*0xA0*/  4,   4,   4,   4,   4,   4,   8,   4,   4,   4,   4,   4,   4,   4,   8,   4,
                                 /*0xB0*/  4,   4,   4,   4,   4,   4,   8,   4,   4,   4,   4,   4,   4,   4,   8,   4,
                                 /*0xC0*/  8,  12,  12,  16,  12,  16,   8,  16,   8,  16,  12,   0,  12,  24,   8,  16,
                                 /*0xD0*/  8,  12,  12,   0,  12,  16,   8,  16,   8,  16,  12,   0,  12,   0,   8,  16,    
                                 /*0xE0*/ 12,  12,   8,   0,   0,  16,   8,  16,  16,   4,  16,   0,   0,   0,   8,  16,
                                 /*0xF0*/ 12,  12,   8,   4,   0,  16,   8,  16,  12,   8,  16,   4,   0,   0,   8,  16
};

// Gameboy bit operation clock cycles
unsigned char GB_CBCycleTable[0x100] = {//0x00 0x01 0x02 0x03 0x04 0x05 0x06 0x07 0x08 0x09 0x0A 0x0B 0x0C 0x0D 0x0E 0x0F
                                 /*0x00*/    8,   8,   8,   8,   8,   8,  16,   8,   8,   8,   8,   8,   8,   8,  16,   8,
                                 /*0x10*/    8,   8,   8,   8,   8,   8,  16,   8,   8,   8,   8,   8,   8,   8,  16,   8,
                                 /*0x20*/    8,   8,   8,   8,   8,   8,  16,   8,   8,   8,   8,   8,   8,   8,  16,   8,
                                 /*0x30*/    8,   8,   8,   8,   8,   8,  16,   8,   8,   8,   8,   8,   8,   8,  16,   8,
                                 /*0x40*/    8,   8,   8,   8,   8,   8,  12,   8,   8,   8,   8,   8,   8,   8,  12,   8,
                                 /*0x50*/    8,   8,   8,   8,   8,   8,  12,   8,   8,   8,   8,   8,   8,   8,  12,   8,
                                 /*0x60*/    8,   8,   8,   8,   8,   8,  12,   8,   8,   8,   8,   8,   8,   8,  12,   8,
                                 /*0x70*/    8,   8,   8,   8,   8,   8,  12,   8,   8,   8,   8,   8,   8,   8,  12,   8,
                                 /*0x80*/    8,   8,   8,   8,   8,   8,  16,   8,   8,   8,   8,   8,   8,   8,  16,   8,
                                 /*0x90*/    8,   8,   8,   8,   8,   8,  16,   8,   8,   8,   8,   8,   8,   8,  16,   8,
                                 /*0xA0*/    8,   8,   8,   8,   8,   8,  16,   8,   8,   8,   8,   8,   8,   8,  16,   8,
                                 /*0xB0*/    8,   8,   8,   8,   8,   8,  16,   8,   8,   8,   8,   8,   8,   8,  16,   8,
                                 /*0xC0*/    8,   8,   8,   8,   8,   8,  16,   8,   8,   8,   8,   8,   8,   8,  16,   8,
                                 /*0xD0*/    8,   8,   8,   8,   8,   8,  16,   8,   8,   8,   8,   8,   8,   8,  16,   8,
                                 /*0xE0*/    8,   8,   8,   8,   8,   8,  16,   8,   8,   8,   8,   8,   8,   8,  16,   8,
                                 /*0xF0*/    8,   8,   8,   8,   8,   8,  16,   8,   8,   8,   8,   8,   8,   8,  16,   8
};

//Blank 8-bit table for possible future use
//unsigned char GB_BitCycleTable[0x100] = {//0x00 0x01 0x02 0x03 0x04 0x05 0x06 0x07 0x08 0x09 0x0A 0x0B 0x0C 0x0D 0x0E 0x0F
//  /*0x00*/     ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,
//  /*0x10*/     ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,
//  /*0x20*/     ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,
//  /*0x30*/     ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,
//  /*0x40*/     ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,
//  /*0x50*/     ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,
//  /*0x60*/     ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,
//  /*0x70*/     ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,
//  /*0x80*/     ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,
//  /*0x90*/     ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,
//  /*0xA0*/     ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,
//  /*0xB0*/     ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,
//  /*0xC0*/     ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,
//  /*0xD0*/     ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,
//  /*0xE0*/     ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,
//  /*0xF0*/     ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,    ,

unsigned char opcodeDescription[256][32];

// An array that holds the pixel data that will actually be drawn to the screen.
unsigned char screenData[0x5A00];

//----------------------------------------//
// Gameboy status arrays.                 //
//----------------------------------------//
unsigned char joyState[8] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

//----------------------------------------//
// Miscellaneous variables                //
//----------------------------------------//
unsigned long long int FPS = 0;

SDL_TimerID FPSTimerID;

// This will check if the read address is readable and return the data from the proper location.
unsigned char ReadMemory(unsigned short int address)
{
    if ((address >= 0x0000) && (address <= 0x3FFF))
        return emu.memory.romBank0[address];
    else if ((address >= 0x4000) && (address <= 0x7FFF))
        return emu.memory.romBank1[address - 0x4000];
    else if ((address >= 0x8000) && (address <= 0x9FFF))
        return emu.memory.videoRam[address - 0x8000];
    else if ((address >= 0xA000) && (address <= 0xBFFF))
        return emu.memory.ramBank[address - 0xA000];
    else if ((address >= 0xC000) && (address <= 0xDFFF))
        return emu.memory.internRam[address - 0xC000];
    else if ((address >= 0xE000) && (address <= 0xFDFF))  // Echo Ram.  Returns the same value as the C000-DDFF space.
        return emu.memory.internRam[address - 0xE000];
    else if ((address >= 0xFE00) && (address <= 0xFE9F))  // Read from the sprite OAM RAM.
        return emu.memory.sprite[address - 0xFE00];
    //else if ((address >= 0xFEA0) && (address <= 0xFEFF))  // Restricted memory space.
    //  return 0xFF;
    else if ((address >= 0xFF00) && (address <= 0xFF4B))  // Read from an I/O register.
    {
        return emu.memory.ioRegs[address - 0xFF00];
    }
    //else if ((address >= 0xFF4C) && (address <= 0xFF7F))  // Restricted memory space.
    //  return 0xFF;
    else if ((address >= 0xFF80) && (address <= 0xFFFE))
        return emu.memory.highRam[address - 0xFF80];
    else if (address == 0xFFFF)
        return emu.memory.intrpFlags;
    else
        return 0xFF;
}

// This will check whether a write to memory is valid and if any special location is written
void WriteMemory(unsigned short int address, unsigned char data)
{
    // Make sure the instruction isn't trying to write to the ROM bank areas.
    if ((address >= 0x0000) && (address <= 0x7FFF))
    {
        // See if this is a special memory write.
        if ((address >= 0x2000) && (address <= 0x3FFF))
            if ((emu.cart.mbcType >= 1) && (emu.cart.mbcType <= 3))
            {
                // 0 or ROM banks that are a multiple of 0x20 refer to the next ROM bank (0x20 = 0x21, 0x40 = 0x41).
                // The low 5 bits of the 7-bit ROM bank are selected here.
//              if ((data % 20) == 0)
//                  data |= 1;
                // This will combine the lower 5 bits of the written data with the ROM bank register.
                emu.cart.romBankRegister = (emu.cart.romBankRegister & 0xE0) | (data & 0x1F);
                emu.cart.romBankRegister = data;
                memcpy(&emu.memory.romBank1[0], &emu.cart.dataBuffer[emu.cart.romBankRegister * 0x4000], 0x4000);
            }
        else if ((address >= 0x4000) && (address <= 0x5FFF))
            if ((emu.cart.mbcType >= 1) && (emu.cart.mbcType <= 3))
            {
                // 0 or ROM banks that are a multiple of 0x20 refer to the next ROM bank (0x20 = 0x21, 0x40 = 0x41).
                // The high 2 bits of the 7-bit ROM bank are selected here.
                emu.cart.romBankRegister = (emu.cart.romBankRegister & 0x1F) | (data & 0x60);
                memcpy(&emu.memory.romBank1[0], &emu.cart.dataBuffer[emu.cart.romBankRegister * 0x4000], 0x4000);
            }
    }

    else if ((address >= 0x8000) && (address <= 0x9FFF))
        emu.memory.videoRam[address - 0x8000] = data;
    else if ((address >= 0xA000) && (address <= 0xBFFF))
        emu.memory.ramBank[address - 0xA000] = data;
    else if ((address >= 0xC000) && (address <= 0xDFFF))
        emu.memory.internRam[address - 0xC000] = data;
    else if ((address >= 0xE000) && (address <= 0xFDFF))  // Echo Ram.  Writes the value to the C000-DDFF space.
        emu.memory.internRam[address - 0xE000] = data;
    else if ((address >= 0xFE00) && (address <= 0xFE9F))  // Write to the sprite OAM RAM.
        emu.memory.sprite[address - 0xFE00] = data;
    else if ((address >= 0xFEA0) && (address <= 0xFEFF))  // Restricted memory space.
        return;
    else if ((address >= 0xFF00) && (address <= 0xFF4B))  // Write to an I/O register.
    {
        if (address == 0xFF00)
            IOregister_P1 = 0xCF + (data & 0x30);  // Only bits 4 and 5 of the P1 register are writable.

        else if (address == 0xFF01)
            IOregister_SB = data;

        else if (address == 0xFF02)
        {
            // If a serial transfer was attempted, set the received data to 0xFF since no second Gameboy is present.
            // The interrupt is only triggered if the system has set itself as the master Gameboy.
            if ((data & BIT_7) && (data & BIT_0))
                IOregister_IF |= BIT_3;
            IOregister_SB = 0xFF;
        }

        // Reset the internal counter if DIV is written to.
        else if (address == 0xFF04)
        {
            emu.cycles.internalCounterCycles = 0;
            emu.cycles.previousInternalCounterCycles = 0;
            emu.cycles.timaIncCounterCycles = 0;
        }

        else if (address == 0xFF05)
            IOregister_TIMA = data;

        else if (address == 0xFF06)
            IOregister_TMA = data;

        else if (address == 0xFF07)
        {
            IOregister_TAC = 0xF8 + (data & 0x07);  // Only the low 3 bits of TAC can be written.

            emu.cycles.timaIncCounterCycles = 0;
            //emu.cycles.previousInternalCounterCycles = 0;
        }
        else if (address == 0xFF0F)
            IOregister_IF = 0xE0 + (data & 0x1F);  // Only the low 5 bits of IF can be written.

        else if (address == 0xFF10)
            IOregister_NR10 = 0x80 + (data & 0x7F);  // The 7th bit always returns 1.

        else if (address == 0xFF40)
        {
            IOregister_LCDC = data;

            if (!(IOregister_LCDC & BIT_7))
            {
                // If the LCD is turned off, STAT mode, LY, and triggered display interrupts are all reset, but the LY/LYC compare bit and enabled STAT interrupt are retained.
                IOregister_STAT &= (BIT_0_OFF & BIT_1_OFF);
                IOregister_LY = 0;
                WYTemp = IOregister_WY;
                //              IOregister_IF &= (BIT_0_OFF & BIT_1_OFF);
                emu.cycles.statCycles = 0;
            }
        }

        else if (address == 0xFF41)
            IOregister_STAT = (BIT_7 | (data & 0x78)) | IOregister_STAT & (BIT_1 | BIT_0);  // Make sure the mode flag is not affected and the 7th bit always returns 1.

        else if (address == 0xFF46)
        {
            IOregister_DMA = data;
            for (int i = 0; i < 0xA0; i++)
                emu.memory.sprite[i] = ReadMemory((IOregister_DMA << 8) + i);  // If data is written to the OAM register, begin an OAM transfer.
        }
        else
            emu.memory.ioRegs[address - 0xFF00] = data;
    }
    //else if ((address >= 0xFF4C) && (address <= 0xFF7F))  // Restricted memory space.
    //  return;
    else if ((address >= 0xFF80) && (address <= 0xFFFE))
        emu.memory.highRam[address - 0xFF80] = data;
    else if (address == 0xFFFF)
        IOregister_IE = 0xE0 + (data & 0x1F);  // Only the low 5-bits of IE can be written.
}

//----------------------------------------//
// This instruction will add a given value//
// plus the carry flag to register A.     //
//----------------------------------------//
void z80_ADC_A_immediate()
{
    unsigned char value;
    value = ReadMemory(emu.cpu.regs.PC);

    // If there is a carry from bit 3, set flag H, otherwise
    // reset it.
    if (((emu.cpu.regs.A & 0xF) + (value & 0xF) + FLAG_C) > 0xF)
        emu.cpu.regs.F |= FLAG_H_ON;
    else
        emu.cpu.regs.F &= FLAG_H_OFF;

    // If there will be a carry from bit 7, set flag C, otherwise
    // reset it.
    if ((emu.cpu.regs.A + value + FLAG_C) > 0xFF)
    {
        emu.cpu.regs.A += value + FLAG_C;
        emu.cpu.regs.F |= FLAG_C_ON;
    }
    else
    {
        emu.cpu.regs.A += value + FLAG_C;
        emu.cpu.regs.F &= FLAG_C_OFF;
    }

    // If result is 0, set flag Z, otherwise reset it.
    if (emu.cpu.regs.A == 0)
        emu.cpu.regs.F |= FLAG_Z_ON;
    else
        emu.cpu.regs.F &= FLAG_Z_OFF;

    // Flag N is reset.
    emu.cpu.regs.F &= FLAG_N_OFF;

    // Increment Program Counter to skip read value.
    emu.cpu.regs.PC++;
}

//----------------------------------------//
// This instruction will add an 8-bit     //
// register plus the carry flag to        //
// register A.                            //
//----------------------------------------//
void z80_ADC_A_reg8(unsigned char *reg)
{
    // If there will be a carry from bit 3, set flag H, otherwise
    // reset it.
    if (((emu.cpu.regs.A & 0xF) + (*reg & 0xF) + FLAG_C) > 0xF)
        emu.cpu.regs.F |= FLAG_H_ON;
    else
        emu.cpu.regs.F &= FLAG_H_OFF;

    // If there will be a carry from bit 7, set flag C, otherwise
    // reset it.
    if ((emu.cpu.regs.A + *reg + FLAG_C) > 0xFF)
    {
        emu.cpu.regs.A += *reg + FLAG_C;
        emu.cpu.regs.F |= FLAG_C_ON;
    }
    else
    {
        emu.cpu.regs.A += *reg + FLAG_C;
        emu.cpu.regs.F &= FLAG_C_OFF;
    }

    // If result is 0, set flag Z, otherwise reset it.
    if (emu.cpu.regs.A == 0)
        emu.cpu.regs.F |= FLAG_Z_ON;
    else
        emu.cpu.regs.F &= FLAG_Z_OFF;

    // Flag N is reset.
    emu.cpu.regs.F &= FLAG_N_OFF;
}

//----------------------------------------//
// This instruction will add a given value//
// to register A.                         //
//----------------------------------------//
void z80_ADD_A_immediate()
{
    unsigned char value;
    value = ReadMemory(emu.cpu.regs.PC);

    // If there will be a carry from bit 3, set flag H, otherwise
    // reset it.
    if (((emu.cpu.regs.A & 0xF) + (value & 0xF)) > 0xF)
        emu.cpu.regs.F |= FLAG_H_ON;
    else
        emu.cpu.regs.F &= FLAG_H_OFF;

    // If there will be a carry from bit 7, set flag C, otherwise
    // reset it.
    if ((emu.cpu.regs.A + value) > 0xFF)
        emu.cpu.regs.F |= FLAG_C_ON;
    else
        emu.cpu.regs.F &= FLAG_C_OFF;

    // Add *reg to register A.
    emu.cpu.regs.A += value;

    // If result is 0, set flag Z, otherwise reset it.
    if (emu.cpu.regs.A == 0)
        emu.cpu.regs.F |= FLAG_Z_ON;
    else
        emu.cpu.regs.F &= FLAG_Z_OFF;

    // Flag N is reset.
    emu.cpu.regs.F &= FLAG_N_OFF;

    emu.cpu.regs.PC++;
}

//----------------------------------------//
// This instruction will add an 8-bit     //
// register's value to register A.        //
//----------------------------------------//
void z80_ADD_A_reg8(unsigned char *reg)
{
    // If there will be a carry from bit 3, set flag H, otherwise
    // reset it.
    if (((emu.cpu.regs.A & 0xF) + (*reg & 0xF)) > 0xF)
        emu.cpu.regs.F |= FLAG_H_ON;
    else
        emu.cpu.regs.F &= FLAG_H_OFF;

    // If there will be a carry from bit 7, set flag C, otherwise
    // reset it.
    if ((emu.cpu.regs.A + *reg) > 0xFF)
        emu.cpu.regs.F |= FLAG_C_ON;
    else
        emu.cpu.regs.F &= FLAG_C_OFF;

    // Add *reg to register A.
    emu.cpu.regs.A += *reg;

    // If result is 0, set flag Z, otherwise reset it.
    if (emu.cpu.regs.A == 0)
        emu.cpu.regs.F |= FLAG_Z_ON;
    else
        emu.cpu.regs.F &= FLAG_Z_OFF;

    // Flag N is reset.
    emu.cpu.regs.F &= FLAG_N_OFF;
}

//----------------------------------------//
// This instruction will add the value of //
// a 16-bit register to register HL.      //
//----------------------------------------//
void z80_ADD_HL_reg16(unsigned short int *reg)
{
    // If there will be a carry from bit 11, set flag H.
    if (((emu.cpu.regs.HL & 0xFFF) + (*reg & 0xFFF)) > 0xFFF)
        emu.cpu.regs.F |= FLAG_H_ON;
    else
        emu.cpu.regs.F &= FLAG_H_OFF;

    // If there will be a carry from bit 15, set flag C.
    if ((emu.cpu.regs.HL + *reg) > 0xFFFF)
        emu.cpu.regs.F |= FLAG_C_ON;
    else
        emu.cpu.regs.F &= FLAG_C_OFF;

    // Add *reg to HL.
    emu.cpu.regs.HL += *reg;

    // Flag N is reset.
    emu.cpu.regs.F &= FLAG_N_OFF;
}

//----------------------------------------//
// This instruction will add a given,     //
// signed 8-bit value to the              //
// Stack pointer.                         //
//----------------------------------------//
void z80_ADD_SP_immediate()
{
    unsigned char value;
    value = ReadMemory(emu.cpu.regs.PC);

    // The flags are determined with an unsigned value.

    // Turn on flag H if there is a carry from bit 3.
    if (((emu.cpu.regs.SP & 0xF) + (value & 0xF)) > 0xF)
        emu.cpu.regs.F |= FLAG_H_ON;
    else
        emu.cpu.regs.F &= FLAG_H_OFF;

    // Turn on flag C if the result is above 0xFFFF, or below 0x0000.
    if (((emu.cpu.regs.SP & 0xFF) + value) > 0xFF)
        emu.cpu.regs.F |= FLAG_C_ON;
    else
        emu.cpu.regs.F &= FLAG_C_OFF;

    emu.cpu.regs.SP += (signed char)value;

    // Flag Z and N are reset.
    emu.cpu.regs.F &= (FLAG_Z_OFF & FLAG_N_OFF);

    emu.cpu.regs.PC++;
}

//----------------------------------------//
// This instruction will logical AND a    //
// given value with register A.           //
//----------------------------------------//
void z80_AND_immediate()
{
    // Logically AND register A with an immediate value.
    emu.cpu.regs.A &= ReadMemory(emu.cpu.regs.PC);

    // If result is 0, set flag Z, otherwise reset it.
    if (emu.cpu.regs.A == 0)
        emu.cpu.regs.F |= FLAG_Z_ON;
    else
        emu.cpu.regs.F &= FLAG_Z_OFF;

    // Flag_H is set.
    emu.cpu.regs.F |= FLAG_H_ON;

    // Flags N and C are reset.
    emu.cpu.regs.F &= (FLAG_N_OFF & FLAG_C_OFF);

    emu.cpu.regs.PC++;
}

//----------------------------------------//
// This instruction will logical AND a    //
// given value with an 8-bit register.    //
//----------------------------------------//
void z80_AND_reg8(unsigned char *reg)
{
    // Logically AND register A with *reg.
    emu.cpu.regs.A &= *reg;

    // If result is 0, set flag Z, otherwise reset it.
    if (emu.cpu.regs.A == 0)
        emu.cpu.regs.F |= FLAG_Z_ON;
    else
        emu.cpu.regs.F &= FLAG_Z_OFF;

    // Flag_H is set.
    emu.cpu.regs.F |= FLAG_H_ON;

    // Flags N and C are reset.
    emu.cpu.regs.F &= (FLAG_N_OFF & FLAG_C_OFF);
}

//----------------------------------------//
// This instruction will test a bit of an //
// 8-bit register.                        //
//----------------------------------------//
void z80_BIT_bit_reg8(unsigned char bit, unsigned char *reg)
{
    // If result is 0, set flag Z, otherwise reset it.
    if ((*reg & bit) == 0)
        emu.cpu.regs.F |= FLAG_Z_ON;
    else
        emu.cpu.regs.F &= FLAG_Z_OFF;

    // Flag N is reset.
    emu.cpu.regs.F &= FLAG_N_OFF;

    // Flag H is set.
    emu.cpu.regs.F |= FLAG_H_ON;
}

//----------------------------------------//
// This instruction will push the current //
// value of the Program Counter onto the  //
// stack and jump to a new address, but   //
// only if the given condition is met.    //
//----------------------------------------//
int z80_CALL_condition_immediate(unsigned char condition)
{
    unsigned short int callAddress;
    unsigned int conditionTrue;

    callAddress = (ReadMemory(emu.cpu.regs.PC) + (ReadMemory(emu.cpu.regs.PC + 1) << 8));
    conditionTrue = 0;

    switch (condition)
    {
    case 0x01:
    {
        if (FLAG_Z == 0)
            conditionTrue = 1;
    }
    break;
    case 0x02:
    {
        if (FLAG_Z == 1)
            conditionTrue = 1;
    }
    break;
    case 0x03:
    {
        if (FLAG_C == 0)
            conditionTrue = 1;
    }
    break;
    case 0x04:
    {
        if (FLAG_C == 1)
            conditionTrue = 1;
    }
    break;
    }

    emu.cpu.regs.PC += 2;

    if (conditionTrue == 1)
    {
        // Push address of next instruction onto the stack.
        emu.cpu.regs.SP--;
        WriteMemory(emu.cpu.regs.SP, emu.cpu.regs.PCH);
        emu.cpu.regs.SP--;
        WriteMemory(emu.cpu.regs.SP, emu.cpu.regs.PCL);

        emu.cpu.regs.PC = callAddress;
        return 12;  // return additional cycles if jump was executed.
    }
    else
        return 0;
}

//----------------------------------------//
// This instruction will push the current //
// value of the Program Counter onto the  //
// stack and jump to a new address.       //
//----------------------------------------//
void z80_CALL_immediate()
{
    unsigned short int callAddress;

    callAddress = ReadMemory(emu.cpu.regs.PC) + (ReadMemory(emu.cpu.regs.PC + 1) << 8);

    emu.cpu.regs.PC += 2;

    // Push address of next instruction onto the stack.
    emu.cpu.regs.SP--;
    WriteMemory(emu.cpu.regs.SP, emu.cpu.regs.PCH);
    emu.cpu.regs.SP--;
    WriteMemory(emu.cpu.regs.SP, emu.cpu.regs.PCL);

    // Load new address into Program Counter.
    emu.cpu.regs.PC = callAddress;
}

//----------------------------------------//
// This instruction will complement(flip) //
// the carry flag.                        //
//----------------------------------------//
void z80_CCF()
{
    // Complement flag C.
    emu.cpu.regs.F ^= FLAG_C_ON;

    // Flags N and H are reset.
    emu.cpu.regs.F &= (FLAG_N_OFF & FLAG_H_OFF);
}

//----------------------------------------//
// This instruction will set flags as if  //
// a given value with subtracted from     //
// register A.                            //
//----------------------------------------//
void z80_CP_immediate()
{
    unsigned char value;
    value = ReadMemory(emu.cpu.regs.PC);

    if (emu.cpu.regs.A == value)
        emu.cpu.regs.F |= FLAG_Z_ON;
    else
        emu.cpu.regs.F &= FLAG_Z_OFF;

    if ((emu.cpu.regs.A & 0xF) < (value & 0xF))
        emu.cpu.regs.F |= FLAG_H_ON;
    else
        emu.cpu.regs.F &= FLAG_H_OFF;

    if (emu.cpu.regs.A < value)
        emu.cpu.regs.F |= FLAG_C_ON;
    else
        emu.cpu.regs.F &= FLAG_C_OFF;

    emu.cpu.regs.F |= FLAG_N_ON;

    emu.cpu.regs.PC++;
}

//----------------------------------------//
// This instruction will set flags as if  //
// a register was subtracted from         //
// register A.                            //
//----------------------------------------//
void z80_CP_reg8(unsigned char *reg)
{
    if (emu.cpu.regs.A == *reg)
        emu.cpu.regs.F |= FLAG_Z_ON;
    else
        emu.cpu.regs.F &= FLAG_Z_OFF;

    if ((emu.cpu.regs.A & 0xF) < (*reg & 0xF))
        emu.cpu.regs.F |= FLAG_H_ON;
    else
        emu.cpu.regs.F &= FLAG_H_OFF;

    if (emu.cpu.regs.A < *reg)
        emu.cpu.regs.F |= FLAG_C_ON;
    else
        emu.cpu.regs.F &= FLAG_C_OFF;

    emu.cpu.regs.F |= FLAG_N_ON;
}

//----------------------------------------//
// This instruction will flip all of      //
// register A's bits.                     //
//----------------------------------------//
void z80_CPL()
{
    // Exclusive OR register A with 0xFF, this will flip the bits.
    emu.cpu.regs.A ^= 0xFF;

    // Flags N and H are set.
    emu.cpu.regs.F |= (FLAG_N_ON | FLAG_H_ON);
}

//----------------------------------------//
// This instruction will convert register //
// A to its packed-BCD representation.    //
//----------------------------------------//
void z80_DAA()
{
    unsigned short int result;

    result = emu.cpu.regs.A;

    // Check if flag N is on indicating the last operation was a subtraction.
    if (FLAG_N == 1)
    {
        if (FLAG_H == 1)
            result = (result - 0x06) & 0xFF;
        if (FLAG_C == 1)
            result -= 0x60;
    }
    // Otherwise, convert for an addition.
    else
    {
        if (((result & 0xF) > 0x09) || (FLAG_H == 1))
            result += 0x06;
        if ((result > 0x9F) || (FLAG_C == 1))
            result += 0x60;
    }

    // Set the carry flag if the BCD value of the result is greater than 99.
    if ((result & 0x100) == 0x100)
        emu.cpu.regs.F |= FLAG_C_ON;
//  else
//      emu.cpu.regs.F &= FLAG_C_OFF;

    emu.cpu.regs.A = (unsigned char)(result & 0xFF);

    // If the result was 0, turn the Z flag on.
    if (emu.cpu.regs.A == 0)
        emu.cpu.regs.F |= FLAG_Z_ON;
    else
        emu.cpu.regs.F &= FLAG_Z_OFF;

    // Flag H is turned off.
    emu.cpu.regs.F &= FLAG_H_OFF;
}

//----------------------------------------//
// This instruction will decrease the     //
// value at memory location (HL) by 1.    //
//----------------------------------------//
void z80_DEC_location_HL()
{
    WriteMemory(emu.cpu.regs.HL, ReadMemory(emu.cpu.regs.HL) - 1);

    // Turn on flag N since operation is a subtraction.
    emu.cpu.regs.F |= FLAG_N_ON;

    if (ReadMemory(emu.cpu.regs.HL) == 0)
        emu.cpu.regs.F |= FLAG_Z_ON;
    else
        emu.cpu.regs.F &= FLAG_Z_OFF;

    if ((ReadMemory(emu.cpu.regs.HL) & 0xF) == 0xF)
        emu.cpu.regs.F |= FLAG_H_ON;
    else
        emu.cpu.regs.F &= FLAG_H_OFF;
}

//----------------------------------------//
// This instruction decreases a given     //
// 16-bit register's value by 1.          //
//----------------------------------------//
void z80_DEC_reg16(unsigned short int *reg)
{
    *reg -= 1;
}

//----------------------------------------//
// This instruction decreases a given     //
// 8-bit register's value by 1.           //
//----------------------------------------//
void z80_DEC_reg8(unsigned char *reg)
{
    // If the lo nibble of the register is 0, then there will be a borrow from bit 4.
    if ((*reg & 0xF) == 0)
        emu.cpu.regs.F |= FLAG_H_ON;
    else
        emu.cpu.regs.F &= FLAG_H_OFF;

    // Decrement *reg
    *reg -= 1;

    // If result is 0, set flag Z, otherwise reset it.
    if (*reg == 0)
        emu.cpu.regs.F |= FLAG_Z_ON;
    else
        emu.cpu.regs.F &= FLAG_Z_OFF;

    // Turn on flag N.
    emu.cpu.regs.F |= FLAG_N_ON;
}

//----------------------------------------//
// This instruction turns off the         //
// Interrupt Master Enable flag.          //
//----------------------------------------//
void z80_DI()
{
    IntrpMasterEnable = 0;
}

//----------------------------------------//
// This instruction turns on the          //
// Interrupt Master Enable flag.          //
//----------------------------------------//
void z80_EI()
{
    IntrpMasterEnable = 1;
}

//----------------------------------------//
// This instruction will halt the GB CPU  //
// until an interrupt occurs.             //
//----------------------------------------//
void z80_HALT()
{
    // Make sure interrupts are enabled before allowing the CPU to halt.
    if (IntrpMasterEnable == 1)
        emu.state.halted = 1;
    else
    {
        if ((IOregister_IE & IOregister_IF & 0x1F) != 0)
            emu.state.haltInstructionRepeat = 1;
        else
            emu.state.halted = 1;
    }
}

//----------------------------------------//
// This instruction will increase the     //
// value at memory location (HL) by 1.    //
//----------------------------------------//
void z80_INC_location_HL()
{
    // See if there will be a carry from bit 3, if there was, set flag H.
    if ((ReadMemory(emu.cpu.regs.HL) & 0xF) == 0xF)
        emu.cpu.regs.F |= FLAG_H_ON;
    else
        emu.cpu.regs.F &= FLAG_H_OFF;

    // Add 1 to the value at the address in register HL.
    WriteMemory(emu.cpu.regs.HL, ReadMemory(emu.cpu.regs.HL) + 1);

    // If result is 0, set flag Z, otherwise reset it.
    if (ReadMemory(emu.cpu.regs.HL) == 0)
        emu.cpu.regs.F |= FLAG_Z_ON;
    else
        emu.cpu.regs.F &= FLAG_Z_OFF;

    // Turn off flag N.
    emu.cpu.regs.F &= FLAG_N_OFF;
}

//----------------------------------------//
// This instruction increases a given     //
// 16-bit register's value by 1.          //
//----------------------------------------//
void z80_INC_reg16(unsigned short int *reg)
{
    *reg += 1;
}

//----------------------------------------//
// This instruction increases a given     //
// 8-bit register's value by 1.           //
//----------------------------------------//
void z80_INC_reg8(unsigned char *reg)
{
    // Turn the H flag on if incrementing the register carries from bit 3.
    if ((*reg & 0xF) == 0xF)
        emu.cpu.regs.F |= FLAG_H_ON;
    else
        emu.cpu.regs.F &= FLAG_H_OFF;

    // Add 1 to *reg.
    *reg += 1;

    // If result is 0, set flag Z, otherwise reset it.
    if (*reg == 0)
        emu.cpu.regs.F |= FLAG_Z_ON;
    else
        emu.cpu.regs.F &= FLAG_Z_OFF;

    // Turn off flag N.  Flag C is not affected.
    emu.cpu.regs.F &= FLAG_N_OFF;
}

void z80_JP_location_HL()
{
    emu.cpu.regs.PC = emu.cpu.regs.HL;
    //emu.cpu.regs.PCL = ReadMemory(emu.cpu.regs.HL);
    //emu.cpu.regs.PCH = ReadMemory(emu.cpu.regs.HL + 1);
}

//----------------------------------------//
// This instruction will relocate the     //
// Program Counter(PC) to a given         //
// immediate address.                     //
//----------------------------------------//
void z80_JP_immediate()
{
    unsigned short int readAddress;

    readAddress = emu.cpu.regs.PC;

    emu.cpu.regs.PCL = ReadMemory(readAddress);
    readAddress++;
    emu.cpu.regs.PCH = ReadMemory(readAddress);
}

//----------------------------------------//
// This instruction will relocate the     //
// Program Counter(PC) to a given address,//
// but only if the given condition is met.//
//----------------------------------------//
int z80_JP_condition_immediate(unsigned char condition)
{
    unsigned short int jumpAddress;
    boolean conditionTrue;

    jumpAddress = (ReadMemory(emu.cpu.regs.PC) + ((ReadMemory(emu.cpu.regs.PC + 1) << 8)));
    conditionTrue = 0;

    switch (condition)
    {
    // If the Z flag is off, jump to the address.
    case 0x01:
    {
        if (FLAG_Z == 0)
            conditionTrue = 1;
    }
    break;
    // If the Z flag is on, jump to the address.
    case 0x02:
    {
        if (FLAG_Z == 1)
            conditionTrue = 1;
    }
    break;
    // If the C flag is off, jump to the address.
    case 0x03:
    {
        if (FLAG_C == 0)
            conditionTrue = 1;
    }
    break;
    // If the C flag is on, jump to the address.
    case 0x04:
    {
        if (FLAG_C == 1)
            conditionTrue = 1;
    }
    break;
    }

    if (conditionTrue == 1)
    {
        emu.cpu.regs.PC = jumpAddress;
        return 4;  // Add four additional cycles if jump succeeds.
    }
    else
    {
        emu.cpu.regs.PC += 2;
        return 0;
    }
}


//----------------------------------------//
// This instruction will add a signed     //
// 8-bit offset to the Program Counter    //
// only if the given condition is met.    //
//----------------------------------------//
int z80_JR_condition_offset(unsigned char condition)
{
    boolean conditionTrue;

    conditionTrue = 0;

    // condition decides the jump condition to look for.
    switch(condition)
    {
    case 0x01:          //JR NZ, offset
    {
        if (FLAG_Z == 0)
            conditionTrue = 1;
    }
    break;
    case 0x02:          //JR Z, offset
    {
        if (FLAG_Z == 1)
            conditionTrue = 1;
    }
    break;
    case 0x03:          //JR NC, offset
    {
        if (FLAG_C == 0)
            conditionTrue = 1;
    }
    break;
    case 0x04:          //JR C, offset
    {
        if (FLAG_C == 1)
            conditionTrue = 1;
    }
    break;
    }

    if (conditionTrue)
    {
        // Relative jump within 128 bytes.
        emu.cpu.regs.PC += (signed char)ReadMemory(emu.cpu.regs.PC);
        emu.cpu.regs.PC++;
        return 4;
    }
    else
        emu.cpu.regs.PC++;

    return 0;
}

//----------------------------------------//
// This instruction will add a signed     //
// 8-bit offset to the Program Counter.   //
//----------------------------------------//
void z80_JR_offset()
{
    // Relative jump within 128 bytes.
    emu.cpu.regs.PC += (signed char)ReadMemory(emu.cpu.regs.PC);
    emu.cpu.regs.PC++;
}

//----------------------------------------//
// This instruction will load the value at//
// a given memory location into A.        //
//----------------------------------------//
void z80_LD_A_location_immediate()
{
    unsigned short int readAddress;
    readAddress = ReadMemory(emu.cpu.regs.PC) + (ReadMemory(emu.cpu.regs.PC + 1) << 8);

    emu.cpu.regs.A = ReadMemory(readAddress);
    emu.cpu.regs.PC += 2;
}

//----------------------------------------//
// This instruction loads the value at    //
// memory location 0xFF00 plus register C //
// into register A.                       //
//----------------------------------------//
void z80_LD_A_0xFF00_C()
{
    // Load the value at 0xFF00 + register C into register A.
    emu.cpu.regs.A = ReadMemory(0xFF00 + emu.cpu.regs.C);
}

//----------------------------------------//
// This instruction will load the value   //
// at memory location 0xFF00 plus an 8-bit//
// value into register A.                 //
//----------------------------------------//
void z80_LD_A_0xFF00_immediate()
{
    unsigned char value;
    value = ReadMemory(emu.cpu.regs.PC);

    // Load the value at 0xFF00 + value into register A.
    emu.cpu.regs.A = ReadMemory(0xFF00 + value);

    emu.cpu.regs.PC++;
}

//----------------------------------------//
// This instruction will load the value in//
// memory at (reg16) into register A.     //
//----------------------------------------//
void z80_LD_A_location_reg16(unsigned short int *reg)
{
    // Load A with the value at the address in *reg.
    emu.cpu.regs.A = ReadMemory(*reg);
}

//----------------------------------------//
// Load the Stack Pointer plus a given,   //
// signed 8-bit value into memory         //
// location (HL).                         //
//----------------------------------------//
void z80_LD_HL_SP_immediate()
{
    unsigned char value;
    value = ReadMemory(emu.cpu.regs.PC);

    // The flags are determined with an unsigned value.

    // Flag H is set if there is a carry from bit 3.
    if (((emu.cpu.regs.SP & 0xF) + (value & 0xF)) > 0xF)
        emu.cpu.regs.F |= FLAG_H_ON;
    else
        emu.cpu.regs.F &= FLAG_H_OFF;

    // Flag C is set if there is a carry from bit 7.
    if ((emu.cpu.regs.SP & 0xFF) + value > 0xFF)
        emu.cpu.regs.F |= FLAG_C_ON;
    else
        emu.cpu.regs.F &= FLAG_C_OFF;

    emu.cpu.regs.HL = emu.cpu.regs.SP + (signed char)value;

    // Reset flags Z and N.
    emu.cpu.regs.F &= (FLAG_Z_OFF & FLAG_N_OFF);

    // Increment Program Counter.
    emu.cpu.regs.PC++;
}

//----------------------------------------//
// This instruction will load a given     //
// value into memory location (HL).       //
//----------------------------------------//
void z80_LD_location_HL_immediate()
{
    unsigned char value;
    value = ReadMemory(emu.cpu.regs.PC);

    // Load the address in HL with the immediate value
    WriteMemory(emu.cpu.regs.HL, value);

    // Increment the Program Counter to skip over the 8-bit value.
    emu.cpu.regs.PC++;
}

//----------------------------------------//
// This instruction will load the value of//
// an 8-bit register into memory location //
// (HL).                                  //
//----------------------------------------//
void z80_LD_location_HL_reg8(unsigned char *reg)
{
    // Load *reg into the address in register HL
    WriteMemory(emu.cpu.regs.HL, *reg);
}

//----------------------------------------//
// This instruction will load the value of//
// register A into memory at a given      //
// location.                              //
//----------------------------------------//
void z80_LD_location_immediate_A()
{
    unsigned short int writeAddress;
    writeAddress = ReadMemory(emu.cpu.regs.PC) + (ReadMemory(emu.cpu.regs.PC + 1) << 8);

    // Load register A into the location.
    WriteMemory(writeAddress, emu.cpu.regs.A);

    // Skip over the 16-bit address.
    emu.cpu.regs.PC += 2;
}

//----------------------------------------//
// This will load the Stack Pointer into a//
// given memory location.                 //
//----------------------------------------//
void z80_LD_location_SP()
{
    unsigned short int writeAddress;
    writeAddress = ReadMemory(emu.cpu.regs.PC) + (ReadMemory(emu.cpu.regs.PC + 1) << 8);

    WriteMemory(writeAddress, emu.cpu.regs.SPL);
    writeAddress++;
    WriteMemory(writeAddress, emu.cpu.regs.SPH);

    // Skip over the 16-bit address.
    emu.cpu.regs.PC += 2;
}

//----------------------------------------//
// This instruction will load a 16-bit    //
// register with a given value.           //
//----------------------------------------//
void z80_LD_reg16_value(unsigned char *hiReg, unsigned char *loReg)
{
    // Load the 16-bit value into the registers.
    *loReg = ReadMemory(emu.cpu.regs.PC);
    emu.cpu.regs.PC++;
    *hiReg = ReadMemory(emu.cpu.regs.PC);
    emu.cpu.regs.PC++;
}

//----------------------------------------//
// This instruction will load the address //
// at a 16-bit pointer register with the  //
// value in register A.                   //
//----------------------------------------//
void z80_LD_location_reg16_A(unsigned short int *reg)
{
    WriteMemory(*reg, emu.cpu.regs.A);
}

//----------------------------------------//
// This instruction will load an 8-bit    //
// register with a given value.           //
//----------------------------------------//
void z80_LD_reg8_value(unsigned char *reg)
{
    // Load *reg with the 8-bit value immediately after it.
    *reg = ReadMemory(emu.cpu.regs.PC);

    // Increment the program counter to skip the value.
    emu.cpu.regs.PC++;
}

//----------------------------------------//
// This instruction will load an 8-bit    //
// register with the value at memory      //
// location (HL).                         //
//----------------------------------------//
void z80_LD_reg8_location_HL(unsigned char *reg)
{
    // Load the value at the address in HL into *reg.
    *reg = ReadMemory(emu.cpu.regs.HL);
}

//----------------------------------------//
// This instruction will load an 8-bit    //
// register with the value of another     //
// 8-bit register.                        //
//----------------------------------------//
void z80_LD_reg8_reg8(unsigned char *reg1, unsigned char *reg2)
{
    // Load the value in *reg2 into *reg1.
    *reg1 = *reg2;
}

//----------------------------------------//
// This instruction will load the Stack   //
// Pointer with the value of register HL. //
//----------------------------------------//
void z80_LD_SP_HL()
{
    // Load register HL into Stack Pointer.
    emu.cpu.regs.SP = emu.cpu.regs.HL;
}

//----------------------------------------//
// This instruction loads register A into //
// memory location 0xFF00 plus register C.//
//----------------------------------------//
void z80_LD_0xFF00_C_A()
{
    WriteMemory(0xFF00 + emu.cpu.regs.C, emu.cpu.regs.A);
}

//----------------------------------------//
// This instruction will load the value   //
// of register A into memory at the       //
// location of 0xFF00 plus an 8-bit value.//
//----------------------------------------//
void z80_LD_0xFF00_immediate_A()
{
    // Write the value of register A into memory.
    WriteMemory(0xFF00 + ReadMemory(emu.cpu.regs.PC), emu.cpu.regs.A);

    // Increment Program Counter
    emu.cpu.regs.PC++;
}

// Load A with data at location HL and decrement HL.
void z80_LDD_A_HL()
{
    emu.cpu.regs.A = ReadMemory(emu.cpu.regs.HL);
    emu.cpu.regs.HL--;
}

// Load location HL with data from register A and decrement HL.
void z80_LDD_HL_A()
{
    WriteMemory(emu.cpu.regs.HL, emu.cpu.regs.A);
    emu.cpu.regs.HL--;
}

// Load A with data at location HL and increment HL.
void z80_LDI_A_HL()
{
    emu.cpu.regs.A = ReadMemory(emu.cpu.regs.HL);
    emu.cpu.regs.HL++;
}

// Load location HL with data from register A and increment HL.
void z80_LDI_HL_A()
{
    WriteMemory(emu.cpu.regs.HL, emu.cpu.regs.A);
    emu.cpu.regs.HL++;
}

//----------------------------------------//
// This instruction will set(turn on) a   //
// given bit of an 8-bit register.        //
//----------------------------------------//
void z80_SET_bit_reg8(unsigned char bit, unsigned char *reg)
{
    *reg |= bit;
}

//----------------------------------------//
// This instruction shifts bit 7 of an    //
// 8-bit register left into the carry flag//
// A 0 is shifted into bit 0.             //
//----------------------------------------//
void z80_SLA_reg8(unsigned char *reg)
{
    // Put *reg's old bit 7 data in Carry flag.
    if (*reg & BIT_7)
        emu.cpu.regs.F |= FLAG_C_ON;
    else
        emu.cpu.regs.F &= FLAG_C_OFF;

    // Shift *reg left once.  0 is shifted in from right.
    *reg <<= 1;

    // If result is 0, set flag Z, otherwise reset it.
    if (*reg == 0)
        emu.cpu.regs.F |= FLAG_Z_ON;
    else
        emu.cpu.regs.F &= FLAG_Z_OFF;

    // Flags N and H are reset.
    emu.cpu.regs.F &= (FLAG_N_OFF & FLAG_H_OFF);
}

//----------------------------------------//
// This instruction shifts bit 0 of an    //
// 8-bit register right into the carry    //
// flag.  Bit 7 doesn't change.           //
//----------------------------------------//
void z80_SRA_reg8(unsigned char *reg)
{
    // Put *reg's old bit 0 data in Carry flag.
    if (*reg & BIT_0)
        emu.cpu.regs.F |= FLAG_C_ON;
    else
        emu.cpu.regs.F &= FLAG_C_OFF;

    // Shift *reg right once.  0 is shifted in from left.  If bit 7
    // is set, make sure it stays set.
    if (*reg & BIT_7)
        *reg = (*reg >> 1) + BIT_7;
    else
        *reg >>= 1;

    // If result is 0, set flag Z, otherwise reset it.
    if (*reg == 0)
        emu.cpu.regs.F |= FLAG_Z_ON;
    else
        emu.cpu.regs.F &= FLAG_Z_OFF;

    // Flags N and H are reset.
    emu.cpu.regs.F &= (FLAG_N_OFF & FLAG_H_OFF);
}

//----------------------------------------//
// This instruction shifts bit 0 of an    //
// 8-bit register right into the carry    //
// flag.  A 0 is shifted into bit 7.      //
//----------------------------------------//
void z80_SRL_reg8(unsigned char *reg)
{
    // Put *reg's old bit 0 data in Carry flag.
    if (*reg & BIT_0)
        emu.cpu.regs.F |= FLAG_C_ON;
    else
        emu.cpu.regs.F &= FLAG_C_OFF;

    // Shift *reg right once.  0 is shifted in from right.
    *reg >>= 1;

    // If result is 0, set flag Z, otherwise reset it.
    if (*reg == 0)
        emu.cpu.regs.F |= FLAG_Z_ON;
    else
        emu.cpu.regs.F &= FLAG_Z_OFF;

    // Flags N and H are reset.
    emu.cpu.regs.F &= (FLAG_N_OFF & FLAG_H_OFF);
}

//----------------------------------------//
// This halts the GB CPU until a button is//
// pressed.                               //
//----------------------------------------//
void z80_STOP()
{
    // Don't allow STOP if interrupts are disabled.
    //if (emu.state.intrpEnable == 1)
        emu.state.stopped = 1;
    // Skip over the extra 0x00
    emu.cpu.regs.PC++;
}

//----------------------------------------//
// This instruction will subtract a given //
// value from register A.                 //
//----------------------------------------//
void z80_SUB_immediate()
{
    unsigned char value;
    value = ReadMemory(emu.cpu.regs.PC);

    // Check for a borrow from bit 4.
    if ((emu.cpu.regs.A & 0xF) < (value & 0xF))
        emu.cpu.regs.F |= FLAG_H_ON;
    else
        emu.cpu.regs.F &= FLAG_H_OFF;

    // Set flag C if result will be below 0.
    if ((emu.cpu.regs.A - value) < 0)
        emu.cpu.regs.F |= FLAG_C_ON;
    else
        emu.cpu.regs.F &= FLAG_C_OFF;

    emu.cpu.regs.A -= value;

    // If result is 0, set flag Z, otherwise reset it.
    if (emu.cpu.regs.A == 0)
        emu.cpu.regs.F |= FLAG_Z_ON;
    else
        emu.cpu.regs.F &= FLAG_Z_OFF;

    // Set N since the operation was a subtraction.
    emu.cpu.regs.F |= FLAG_N_ON;

    emu.cpu.regs.PC++;
}

//----------------------------------------//
// This instruction will subtract an 8-bit//
// register's value from register A.      //
//----------------------------------------//
void z80_SUB_reg8(unsigned char *reg)
{
    // Check for a borrow from bit 4.
    if ((emu.cpu.regs.A & 0xF) < (*reg & 0xF))
        emu.cpu.regs.F |= FLAG_H_ON;
    else
        emu.cpu.regs.F &= FLAG_H_OFF;

    // Set flag C if result will be below 0.
    if ((emu.cpu.regs.A - *reg) < 0)
        emu.cpu.regs.F |= FLAG_C_ON;
    else
        emu.cpu.regs.F &= FLAG_C_OFF;

    emu.cpu.regs.A -= *reg;

    // If result is 0, set flag Z, otherwise reset it.
    if (emu.cpu.regs.A == 0)
        emu.cpu.regs.F |= FLAG_Z_ON;
    else
        emu.cpu.regs.F &= FLAG_Z_OFF;

    // Set N since the operation was a subtraction.
    emu.cpu.regs.F |= FLAG_N_ON;
}

//----------------------------------------//
// This instruction swaps the higher and  //
// lower 4-bits of an 8-bit register.     //
//----------------------------------------//
void z80_SWAP_reg8(unsigned char *reg)
{
    // Swap the upper and lower nibbles of *reg.
    *reg = (((*reg & 0xF0) >> 4) | ((*reg & 0x0F) << 4));

    // If the result was 0, set flag Z, otherwise reset it.
    if(*reg == 0)
        emu.cpu.regs.F |= FLAG_Z_ON;
    else
        emu.cpu.regs.F &= FLAG_Z_OFF;

    // Other flags are reset.
    emu.cpu.regs.F &= (FLAG_N_OFF & FLAG_H_OFF & FLAG_C_OFF);
}

//----------------------------------------//
// This will exclusive OR a given value   //
// and register A.                        //
//----------------------------------------//
void z80_XOR_immediate()
{
    // Logically Exclusive OR register A and an immediate value.
    emu.cpu.regs.A ^= ReadMemory(emu.cpu.regs.PC);

    // If the result was 0, set flag Z, otherwise reset it.
    if (emu.cpu.regs.A == 0)
        emu.cpu.regs.F |= FLAG_Z_ON;
    else
        emu.cpu.regs.F &= FLAG_Z_OFF;

    // Other flags are reset.
    emu.cpu.regs.F &= (FLAG_N_OFF & FLAG_H_OFF & FLAG_C_OFF);

    // Increment Program Counter.
    emu.cpu.regs.PC++;
}

//----------------------------------------//
// This will exclusive OR an 8-bit        //
// register and register A.               //
//----------------------------------------//
void z80_XOR_reg8(unsigned char *reg)
{
    // Logically Exclusive OR register A and *reg.
    emu.cpu.regs.A ^= *reg;

    // If the result was 0, set flag Z, otherwise reset it.
    if (emu.cpu.regs.A == 0)
        emu.cpu.regs.F |= FLAG_Z_ON;
    else
        emu.cpu.regs.F &= FLAG_Z_OFF;

    // Other flags are reset.
    emu.cpu.regs.F &= (FLAG_N_OFF & FLAG_H_OFF & FLAG_C_OFF);
}

//----------------------------------------//
// This function will initialize the GB   //
// to it's startup state.
//----------------------------------------//
int EmulationInitialize(unsigned char *fileBuffer, unsigned int fileSize)
{
    //emu.cart.dataBuffer = (unsigned char *)malloc(fileSize);
    //if (!emu.cart.dataBuffer)
    //  return -1;
    memcpy(&emu.cart.dataBuffer[0], &fileBuffer[0], fileSize);  // Copy ROM file data to cartridge buffer 
    if (emu.cart.dataBuffer[0x0143] == 0x80)
        emu.cart.systemType = SYSTEM_CGB;
    if (emu.cart.dataBuffer[0x0146] == 0x03)
        emu.cart.systemType = SYSTEM_SGB;
    if (emu.cart.dataBuffer[0x0146] == 0x00)
        emu.cart.systemType = SYSTEM_GB;

    if ((emu.cart.systemType != SYSTEM_GB) && (emu.cart.systemType != SYSTEM_SGB)) // Only original Gameboy supported for now.
        return -1;

    emu.cart.mbcType = emu.cart.dataBuffer[0x147];
    //----------------------------------------//
    // Set the CPU and IO register startup    //
    // values.                                //
    //----------------------------------------//
//  if (emu.cart.systemType == SYSTEM_GB)
//  {
        IOregister_NR52 = 0xF1;
        emu.cpu.regs.AF = 0x01B0;
//  }
//  else
//      emu.cpu.regs.AF = 0x00B0;
    emu.cpu.regs.BC = 0x0013;
    emu.cpu.regs.DE = 0x00D8;
    emu.cpu.regs.HL = 0x014D;
    emu.cpu.regs.SP = 0xFFFE;
    emu.cpu.regs.PC = 0x0100;

    IOregister_P1 =     0xCF;
    IOregister_SB =     0x00;
    IOregister_SC =     0x7E;
    IOregister_DIV =    0xAB;
    IOregister_TIMA =   0x00;
    IOregister_TMA =    0x00;
    IOregister_TAC =    0x00;
    IOregister_IF =     0xE1;
    IOregister_NR10 =   0x80;
    IOregister_NR11 =   0xBF;
    IOregister_NR12 =   0xF3;
    IOregister_NR14 =   0xBF;
    IOregister_NR21 =   0xF3;
    IOregister_NR12 =   0xF3;
    IOregister_NR22 =   0x00;
    IOregister_NR24 =   0xBF;
    IOregister_NR30 =   0x7F;
    IOregister_NR31 =   0xFF;
    IOregister_NR32 =   0x9F;
    IOregister_NR33 =   0xBF;
    IOregister_NR41 =   0xFF;
    IOregister_NR42 =   0x00;
    IOregister_NR43 =   0x00;
    IOregister_NR44 =   0xBF;
    IOregister_NR50 =   0x77;
    IOregister_NR51 =   0xF3;
    IOregister_LCDC =   0x91;
    IOregister_STAT =   0x81;
    IOregister_SCY =    0x00;
    IOregister_SCX =    0x00;
    IOregister_LY =     0x90;
    IOregister_LYC =    0x00;
    IOregister_DMA =    0x00;
    IOregister_BGP =    0xFC;
    IOregister_OBP0 =   0xFF;
    IOregister_OBP1 =   0xFF;
    IOregister_WY =     0x00;
    IOregister_WX =     0x07;
    IOregister_IE =     0x00;

    IntrpMasterEnable = 1;

    // Assume standard Gameboy opcode cycles for now
    memcpy(&emu.cycles.opCycles[0], &GB_CycleTable[0], 0x100);
    memcpy(&emu.cycles.opCBCycles[0], &GB_CBCycleTable[0], 0x100);

    //----------------------------------------//
    // Load the base ROM (32K).               //
    //----------------------------------------//
    memcpy(&emu.memory.romBank0[0x0000], &emu.cart.dataBuffer[0x0000], 0x4000);
    memcpy(&emu.memory.romBank1[0x0000], &emu.cart.dataBuffer[0x4000], 0x4000);

    // Clear the video RAM.
    memset(&emu.memory.videoRam, 0, 0x2000);

    emu.cycles.statCycles = 0;
    emu.cycles.internalCounterCycles = 0xABCC;

    emu.state.halted = 0;
    emu.state.haltInstructionRepeat = 0;
    emu.state.stopped = 0;

    return 1;   
}

//----------------------------------------//
// This function takes care of the main GB//
// CPU processes.                         //
//----------------------------------------//
void RunEmulation()
{
    unsigned int systemRunning = 1;
    unsigned int conditionalCycles = 0;
    unsigned int cyclesRan = 0;

    while (systemRunning)
    {
        cyclesRan += HandleInterrupts();

        if (emu.state.eiDelay == 1)
        {
            emu.state.eiDelay = 0;
            IntrpMasterEnable = 1;
        }

                    // Get the value from memory at the HL pointer in case an operation needs it.
        hlMemVal = ReadMemory(emu.cpu.regs.HL);

        // Don't actually execute an opcode if the system is halted or stopped.
        if ((emu.state.halted == 0) && (emu.state.stopped == 0))
        {
            opcode = ReadMemory(emu.cpu.regs.PC);

            if (emu.state.haltInstructionRepeat == 1) // If the halt bug occured, don't increment PC for one instruction.
                emu.state.haltInstructionRepeat = 0;
            else
                emu.cpu.regs.PC++;

            // Use the opcode to call the appropriate function.
            switch (opcode)
            {
   // *switch statement covering all opcodes from 0x00 to 0xFF
                    // Cover the special 0xCB opcodes.
                case 0xCB:
                {
                    cbOpcode = ReadMemory(emu.cpu.regs.PC);
                    emu.cpu.regs.PC++;
                    switch (cbOpcode)
                    {
    // *switch statement covering special CB opcodes.
                    }
                    break;
                    }
                }
                break;

                }
                break;
                }
            }

        // If the opcode was 0xCB, add cycles from the bit operation cycle table.
        if (opcode == 0xCB)
            cyclesRan += emu.cycles.opCBCycles[cbOpcode];
        else
            cyclesRan += emu.cycles.opCycles[opcode] + conditionalCycles;

        // If the last instruction ran was a HALT or a STOP, run cycles until the system resumes.
        if ((opcode == 0x76) || (opcode == 0x10))
            cyclesRan += 4;

        if (IOregister_LCDC & BIT_7)
            emu.cycles.statCycles += cyclesRan;

        emu.cycles.internalCounterCycles += cyclesRan;

        UpdateIORegisters();

        conditionalCycles = 0;  // Reset the conditional cycles added if an instruction's condition was true.
        cyclesRan = 0;  // Reset the total cycles ran.

        HandleSDLEvents();
    }
}
```

Comment: " are there parts of the code that stick out and say "unprofessional"?" 1) Try compiling this code using only what is posted and <> headers.  `#include "define.h"` belongs here as part of the review. 2) The nice tables for `GB_CycleTable[0x100]` and others are not productive - too much effort to maintain.  Use auto formating.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  I would've liked to include the relevant code, but the body character limit prevented it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm just looking for some general critiques.

**Fixed width types**

Rather than `int, unsigned char, unsigned short`, I'd go right into using `int32_t, uint8_t, uint16_t`.  It conveys code's intent and is more portable amongst platforms with variant `int` size.

Fixed width types do prevent portability to non 2's complement machines and those with `CHAR_BIT > 8`, yet those rare platforms are likely very troublesome to code this task for anyways.

**Complete memory map**

Consider a complete 64k map including the *unusable* locations.  Perhaps use a `union` of 64k bytes.  Certain to simplify `ReadMemory()` and `WriteMemory()`.

**Reliance on packed structures**

`regs` only makes sense if `struct` are packed.  As packing tends to be implementation defined, consider adding `_Static_assert()` to insure adherence.

```
    union Registers
    {
        struct { unsigned short int AF, BC, DE, HL, SP, PC; };
        struct { unsigned char F, A, C, B, E, D, L, H, SPL, SPH, PCL, PCH; };
    } regs;

    _Static_assert(offsetof(regs, PC) == 10, "Oops, `short` not packed as expected");  
    _Static_assert(offsetof(regs, PCH) == 11, "Oops, `char` not packed as expected");
```

**Use more than one .c file**

Perhaps one for instructions, memory, etc?

**Unneeded code**

`address >= 0x0000` is always true as `address` is *unsigned*.  It may look symmetric in code presentation, yet it can trigger warnings.  Recommend deletion.

**Unclear code source**

`BIT_7`, `BIT_0` and *many* others are not defined here.  Where are they defined? If in `#include "define.h"`, I'd expect that file posted here too so reviewers may successfully compile.

**Minor: Powers of 2 as decimal**

Powers of 2 as decimal constants, more than 1024, like `16777216` tend to be easy to mis-code and harder to review.

Code could use `16*1024*1204` but that has problems too.  See [There are reasons not to use `1000 * 1000 * 1000`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40637622/2410359)

Usually better to append a `u` to insure the constant is *unsigned* when coding powers-of-2 and especially powers-of-2-minus-1.

**Minor: Format to presentation width**

Code should readily accommodate, through an auto formatter, the presentation width and not run-off to the right.

```
unsigned char GB_CycleTable[0x100] = { //0x00 0x01 0x02 0x03 0x04 0x05 0x06 0x07 0x08 0x09 0x0A 0x0B 0x0C 0x0D 0x0E 0x0F
                                 /*0x00*/  4,  12,   8,   8,   4,   4,   8,   4,  20,   8,   8,   8,   4,   4,   8,   4,
                                 /*0x10*/  0,  12,   8,   8,   4,   4,   8,   4,  12,   8,   8,   8,   4,   4,   8,   4,
                                 /*0x20*/  8,  12,   8,   8,   4,   4,   8,   4,   8,   8,   8,   8,   4,   4,   8,   4,
                                 /*0x30*/  8,  12,   8,   8,  12,  12,  12,   4,   8,   8,   8,   8,   4,   4,   8,   4,
...
                                 /*0xF0*/ 12,  12,   8,   4,   0,  16,   8,  16,  12,   8,  16,   4,   0,   0,   8,  16
};
```

vs.

```
unsigned char GB_CycleTable[0x100] = {
    /*0x00*/4, 12, 8, 8, 4, 4, 8, 4, 20, 8, 8, 8, 4, 4, 8, 4,
    /*0x10*/0, 12, 8, 8, 4, 4, 8, 4, 12, 8, 8, 8, 4, 4, 8, 4,
    /*0x20*/8, 12, 8, 8, 4, 4, 8, 4, 8, 8, 8, 8, 4, 4, 8, 4,
    ....
```

Other alternatives

Since all are small multiples of 4, use `#define` or `enum`

```
#define M1 4
#define M2 8
#define M3 12
#define M4 16
#define M5 20
#define M6 24

/*0x00*/ M1, M3, M2, M2, M1, M1, M2, M1, M5, M2, M2, M2, M1, M1, M2, M1,
```

If you really want to line up the columns, use 8 0xXX values/line.

In this narrow case, I'd even consider 2-digit *octal* as all values appear to be < 64.